# How to install Oracle Database 11g Express Edition on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, database, oracle

I installed the Oracle database following the [steps mentioned in this blog](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html?showComment=1357195285714#c4393074524447658792).

1. Downloaded 11g express edition
2. Created a new user `oracle` under the group `dba`. Following steps are executed using this.
3. Unzipped `oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip` and then converted the `rpm` to the Ubuntu package by running:

   ```
   sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
   ```
4. Created `/sbin/chkconfig` file and added the entries as specified there.
5. Created `/etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf` and added the entries as specified in the same link as above.
6. Running the commands:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk
   mkdir /var/lock/subsys
   touch /var/lock/subsys/listener
   ```
7. .deb generated in step 3:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
   ```
8. Left the default values as it is:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
   ```
9. Set the following env variables in `~/.bashrc` file:

   ```
   export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
   export ORACLE_SID=XE
   export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
   export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
10. Running the commands:

    ```
    chown -R oracle:dba /var/tmp/.oracle
    chmod -R 755 /var/tmp/.oracle
    chown -R oracle:dba /tmp/.oracle
    chmod -R 755 /tmp/.oracle
    ```
11. Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance:

    ```
    sudo service oracle-xe start
    ```
12. sqlplus / as sysdba and got the following:

    ```
    SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Jan 3 09:41:58 2013

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle. All rights reserved.

    Connected to an idle instance.
    ```

Now when exectuting any SQL statements on SQLplus, I end up with the following error:

```
SQL> select * from dual;
select * from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I have increased the swap memory [as specified here](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2011/09/installing-1-gb-swap-without.html)

```
$ free -m
total used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 3901 3428 473 0 182 1988
-/+ buffers/cache: 1258 2643
Swap: 5066 0 5066
```

Comment: please give a solution.i am in a big problem

Answer (score 4):

You will need to do this before you configure oracle.

```
sudo rm -rf /dev/shm
sudo mkdir /dev/shm
sudo mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm
```

Further details are in [another post](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2012/06/trouble-shooting-oracle-11g.html) on the same blog that you referrred.